# UIAlertview valueForKey:@"_backgroundImageView"

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to change the text color and background color of ui alert view. I was using the following code,
UILabel *theTitle = [alertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
        [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

```
    UILabel *theBody = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
    [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];


  UIImageView *backgroundImageView = (UIImageView *)[alertView valueForKey:@"_backgroundImageView"];
   [backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

this was working fine in ios 6. But after upgrading to ios 7, this method is not working. I dont want to create custom uialertview. Please suggest any simple solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in iOS7, `UIAlertViews` are not customizable anymore.

You'll have to stick to their style, or create your own from a `UIView`, but you cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7, `UIAlertView` is nothing but a data container. It just takes the parameters you set and displays them in a private view hierarchy on a private window. Your alert view is never added to any view hierarchy.

Either roll your own alert view implementation or use an open source one, like DTAlertView: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dtalertview